# GWT 2 CssResource how to

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT 1.7 application and I want to upgrade it to GWT 2 Milestone 2. The application uses 2 big external CSS files. In GWT 1.7 I had a public folder and put both the CSS files in the folder and my application compiled and worked fine. Now for GWT 2 I have created a ResourceBundle class and put all image sprites and CSS as follows:

```
public interface ResourceBundle extends ClientBundle {

 public static final ResourceBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(ResourceBundle.class);

 @Source("com/web/tech/public/stylesheet1.css")
 public Css stylesheet1();

 @Source("com/web/tech/public/stylesheet2.css")
 public Css stylesheet2();

 @Source("com/docobo/keswick/keswickweb/public/images/organisnew.gif")
 public ImageResource add_org();

.....
}
```

The Css class is an empty class extending CssResource :

```
public interface Css extends CssResource{

}
```

Then in my onModuleLoad() I use :

```
StyleInjector.inject(ResourceBundle.INSTANCE.stylesheet1().getText());
StyleInjector.inject(ResourceBundle.INSTANCE.stylesheet2().getText());
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
     Rebinding com.docobo.keswick.keswickweb.client.ClientResources.ResourceBundle
            Invoking <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator'/>
               Creating assignment for gxt_gray()
                  Replacing CSS class names
                     [ERROR] The following unobfuscated classes were present in a strict CssResource:
                        [ERROR] x-tab-scroller-left
                        [ERROR] x-tab-strip-disabled
                        [ERROR] ......loads of other styles

Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or using an @external declaration for unobfuscated classes.
```

Following the above instruction when I use @external above all my style classes inside the CSS file I get the following error :

```
 [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator' threw threw an exception while rebinding 'com.docobo.keswick.keswickweb.client.ClientResources.ResourceBundle'
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.gwt.resources.css.GenerateCssAst$GenerationHandler.ignorableAtRule(GenerateCssAst.java:236)
 at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.atRuleDeclaration(Parser.java:1178)
 at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.ignoreStatement(Parser.java:622)
 at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.parserUnit(Parser.java:452)
 at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.parseStyleSheet(Parser.java:107)
 at org.w3c.flute.parser.Parser.parseStyleSheet(Parser.java:119)
 at com.google.gwt.resources.css.GenerateCssAst.exec(GenerateCssAst.java:663)
 at com.google.gwt.resources.rg.CssResourceGenerator.prepare(CssResourceGenerator.java:506)
 at com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.AbstractClientBundleGenerator.initAndPrepare(AbstractClientBundleGenerator.java:531)
 at com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.AbstractClientBundleGenerator.initAndPrepare(AbstractClientBundleGenerator.java:502)
 at com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.AbstractClientBundleGenerator.generate(AbstractClientBundleGenerator.java:179)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:49)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.tryRebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:108)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:54)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:154)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:143)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile$DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(Precompile.java:315)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:107)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:161)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:84)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:196)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$CompilerImpl.access$300(AbstractCompiler.java:70)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:481)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:113)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:49)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:415)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:32)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:507)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:408)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:194)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:145)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:89)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:83)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:152)
```

Answer (score 15):

Try with `@NotStrict`. Example:

```
@NotStrict
@Source("com/web/tech/public/stylesheet1.css")
public Css stylesheet1();
```

Comment: `@NotStrict` is "not recommended for new code": http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.NotStrict.html

Answer (score 7):

Got it solved.
As pointed out by Thomas@Google Groups --> The @external must not be put "above" the style

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#External...

The example from this link, the css will look like :

```
@external .legacySelectorA, .legacySelectorB;
.obfuscated .legacySelectorA { .... }
.obfuscated .legacySelectorB { .... }

/* @external also accepts tail-globs */
@external .myProject-*;
.myProject-text {}
.myProject-foo {}
```