# Change the style of a GWT CellTable dynamically, to visually mark it as disabled

Tags: java, css, gwt

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change the style of a GWT CellTable at runtime.  I want to make the table look "disabled" by graying the color scheme, to match up with other input fields that are disabled.  Right now, I can prevent people from using the table, but they don't get any visual hint.

I have a resource bundle to set the style of the table, like described [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369356/celltables-and-css-gwt):

```
public interface DataTableStyle extends CellTable.Resources {
    @Override
    @Source({ CellTable.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "DataTable.css" })
    CellTable.Style cellTableStyle();
}
```

That's passed into the constructor, and has been working fine for a while now:

```
public DataTable(int pageSize) {
    super(pageSize, getStyle());
}

protected static DataTableStyle getStyle() {
    return GWT.create(DataTableStyle.class);
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to dynamically adjust the style of the table at runtime.  I'm not sure whether it's not possible, or whether I'm just missing something.

I'm pretty sure that I can't change the style resources attached to the cell table once they're set.  Since I can't do that, it seems like I should be able to use either `addStyleDependentName()` or `addStyleName()` in combination with additional CSS styles, but I can't figure out the right combination of changes.

To test, I tried to override my existing definition of `.cellTableHeader`.  I know that I'm targeting the right style, because if I change `background: #000000` to `background: magenta` in the original style, it works.

```
.cellTableHeader {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

One example I worked off of is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Q1rwV4vDgy0).  That page suggests using CSS like this:

```
.cellTableHeader.cellTable-disabled {
    background: magenta; /* just to make it obvious */
}
```

Then, in my code:

```
userTable.addStyleDependentName("disabled")
```

By itself, the `.cellTableHeader.cellTable-disabled` style results in a runtime error:

```
The following unobfuscated classes were present in a strict CssResource:
cellTable-disabled
Fix by adding String accessor method(s) to the CssResource interface for obfuscated classes, or using an @external declaration for unobfuscated classes.
```

The [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701651/gwt-2-cssresource-how-to) workarounds are either to use `@external` on the style or annotate `@NotStrict` on the resource bundle.  Both of those get me past the runtime error, but the style doesn't take effect.  I've also tried various other things:

```
.cellTableHeader.disabled {
    background: magenta; /* just to make it obvious */
}
```

or

```
.cellTableHeader .disabled {
    background: magenta; /* just to make it obvious */
}
```

or

```
.cellTableHeader disabled {
    background: magenta; /* just to make it obvious */
}
```

but at this point I'm really just grasping at straws.

Comment: For now, the way I'm working around this is to create two table/pager pairs with the same data source, within different HTMLPanels in the UI binder.  Then, when I need the disabled state, I hide one HTML panel and show the other.  It's a little clunky, but it at least gets me the visual hint that's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the style resource directly at runtime.

I see two solutions:

**Custom CellTableBuilder**

With this solution the Style used by the CellTableBuilder is replaced at runtime, when the table is re-drawn the new style will be applied. This solution has an issue, the CellTable don't use the CellTableBuilder to set selection styles, therefore replacing style on the builder has no effect on the selection style.

[Here](http://federico.defaveri.org/projects/CustomTableStyle/) a demo of the custom CellTableBuilder solution with the source code.

**Style Proxy**

A different solution is to proxy the Style used by the CellTable and the builder. At runtime you can change the effective Style used by the proxy. Because the DefaultCellTableBuilder stores the style values at construction time you need to create a custom one that don't cache it. I've found no issues, but I've not deeply tested it

[Here](http://federico.defaveri.org/projects/CustomTableStyle2/) a demo of the style proxy solution with the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not sure I understand how this is an improvement over what I have.  I'm already able to set my own styles when I create the table.  What would this gain me over that?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but after looking at the code for DefaultCellTable Builder it seems like this solution has the same limitation that the style can only be set once, when the table is created.

Comment: The table builder is also used to redraw the table, therefore you can set the disabled style and ask the table to be re-drawn.

Comment: Aha!  That makes more sense.  As soon as I get a chance, I'll rework my existing code using one of your solutions.